# jQuery click _blank

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

With help from you guys I now have a script that works like a charm.. The only thing I need now, is the script to open the URL in a new tab/window.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#onskeliste li").click(
    function()
    {
        window.location = $(this).attr("url");
        return false;
    });
    $('#onskeliste li a').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Can you help me with this?? :-)

Comment: I tried using:
window.location = $(this).attr("url");
this.target = "_blank";

But it didn't work... :/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of using `window.location` you should use `window.open()` to open a new window (or tab) instead of loading the URL in the current one.

[Window open() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

Answer (score 4):

```
$(function(){
    $('a.new-window').click(function(){
        window.open(this.href);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#onskeliste li").click( 
    function() 
    { 
        e.preventDefault(); 
        window.open($(this).attr('url'));
    }); 
    $('#onskeliste li a').click(function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault(); 
        window.open($(this).attr('url'));
    }); 

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#onskeliste li").click(
    function()
    {
        window.open($(this).attr("url"));
        return false;
    });
    $('#onskeliste li a').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

})(jQuery);
```