# Jquery Open in new Tab (_blank)

Tags: jquery

I've setup some Jquery based off other StackOverflow questions/answers. The purpose of this script is that it makes an entire div a link based on any a href tag that is inside that div.

This works fine however I need to set it to _blank to open in a new tab. I've tried the below with no luck.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".product-item").click(function() {
        $(this).target = "_blank";
        window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
        return false;
    });
});
```

EDIT

Thanks for the help but none of these answers actually work. If anyone can paste the full code that actually works, rather than little snippets without testing if it works. Thanks.

EDIT 2

Thanks to **kristinalim**, for providing a complete working solution.

Comment: This has been answered before:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827637/how-can-i-open-a-link-in-a-new-window

Comment: `window.location` **always** refers to the location of the current window. Changing it will affect **only** the current window.

Comment: $(".product-item").click(function(){
   $(this).find("a").attr("href");
   window.open(this);
   return false;   
    });

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Setting links on the page woud require a combination of @Ravi and @ncksllvn's answers:

```
// Find link in $(".product-item") and set "target" attribute to "_blank".
$(this).find("a").attr("target", "_blank");
```

For opening the page in another window, see this question: [jQuery click _blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629473/jquery-click-blank) And see [this reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) for `window.open` options for customization.

**Update**:

You would need something along:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".product-item").click(function() {
    var productLink = $(this).find("a");

    productLink.attr("target", "_blank");
    window.open(productLink.attr("href"));

    return false;
  });
});
```

Note the usage of [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
$element.attr("attribute_name")                   // Get value of attribute.
$element.attr("attribute_name", attribute_value)  // Set value of attribute.
```

Comment: Hi Kristina, this seems to be on track. Can you look at the code below and let me know what's wrong.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".product-item").click(function(){
   $(this).find("a").target = "_blank";
   window.open(this.href);
   return false;   
    });
});

Comment: Thankyou Kristina, that works. 10 Points for fully answering a question :)

Comment: worked for me :) Thank you

Comment: Just what I needed thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Replace this line:

```
$(this).target = "_blank";
```

With:

```
$( this ).attr( 'target', '_blank' );
```

That will set its HREF to _blank.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot set target attribute to div, becacuse div does not know how to handle http requests. 
instead of you set target attribute for link tag.

```
$(this).find("a").target = "_blank";
window.location= $(this).find("a").attr("href")
```

Answer (score 1):

`window.location` **always** refers to the location of the current window. Changing it will affect **only** the current window.

One thing that can be done is forcing a click on the link after setting its `target` attribute to `_blank`:

*Check this:* http://www.techfoobar.com/2012/jquery-programmatically-clicking-a-link-and-forcing-the-default-action

*Disclaimer:* Its my blog.