# How to open link before firing jQuery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, href

I'm sure there is a simple answer to this, but I can't see it ;)

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="kunden">
<ul class="kunden-logos">
<li><a href="A LINK" target="_blank"><img src="AN IMAGE" border="0" /></a></li>
<li><a href="ANOTHER LINK" target="_blank"><img src="ANOTHER IMAGE" border="0" /></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$("#kunden").click(function() {
$("#kunden").animate({
height: "-=20%"
}, 1500 ).removeClass('open');
$("#kunden").css({
backgroundSize: "15%", backgroundImage: "url('AN IMAGE')"
});
$("#kunden .hide").css({
display: "none", margin: "0"
});
```

How do I get the link to open in a new window before firing the jQuery?

EDIT: I need to distinguish between more than one links in the #kunden div!

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#kunden").click(function() {
    $("#kunden").animate({
        height: "-=20%"
    }, 1500).removeClass('open');
    $("#kunden").css({
        backgroundSize: "15%", backgroundImage: "url('AN IMAGE')"
    });
    $("#kunden .hide").css({
        display: "none", margin: "0"
    });
});
$('#kunden ul li a').each(function() {
   window.open($(this).attr('href'));
})
```

Comment: Thanks nauphal. How do I apply that to one of more links (see edit!)...?

Comment: @RichardTinkler: I have updated the answer. Now it will open all the links with in `#kunden`

Comment: I need only the link that is clicked on to open, not all of them. Is this possible?

Comment: Thanks nauphal. I removed the .each(function(){}) to ensure that ONLY the link clicked gets opened!

Answer (score 2):

You can [open the link programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950269/jquery-open-in-new-tab-blank) using @kristinalim solution.

Simply open the link in your click event function right before your animation. On a side note, jQuery selection is expensive to use repetitively, you can however cache it.

```
kunden = $("#kunden");
kunden.css({ ... });
```